# Ceramic space heater: Can i cut the wattage in half?

Tags: power-supply

I got a 500w ceramic core space heater that produces to much heat for my project. Is there a easy way to cut the wattage in half and thereby get less effect I.E. heat from the heater?

Comment: Watts = V * I, reduce the voltage or current and you can reduce the wattage by a proportional amount. You can use a rheostat.

Comment: You can always buy two and put in series,  or modify by taking two parallel windings in side to put in series, if possible. or get a triac dimmer.  ( simple) What are you heating up?

Comment: @RonBeyer A rheostat is not a good choice here -- it'd have to dissipate a considerable amount of power itself.

Comment: Turn on and off quickly, you will get the average. So you can have 10%, half, whatever your accuracy is.

Answer (score 5):

The heater most likely has a AC type fan, so you do not want to interfere with its operation.

Internally for the 'hot' wire going to just the heating element you can insert 2 each 6A06 or 6A10 6 amp diodes in parallel for a 12 amp rating, with a 0.1 ohm 5 watt resistor in series with each diode to balance out the load they see.

*Make sure the white 'cathode' band on each diode is pointed in the same direction, such as the heating element*.

250 Watts of power is only about 2 amps drawn from the AC line, but the startup current is 3 times that for a couple of seconds. These diodes may get very warm but that is normal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvN6xh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Actually, you'll get less than half the power. Heater coils always have positive temperature coefficient.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast. I am counting on that. This 'trick' would not work with the outdated nickel-chrome heating element-way too much current and no PTC.